# Cython external library

Tags: python, wrapper, cython

So I'm trying to include steam api library and I can't figure out how to do that in setup.py.

Currently I have:

```
from distutils.core import setup    
from distutils.extension import Extension    
from Cython.Build import cythonize    
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext


extensions = cythonize([
    Extension("test", ["test.pyx"],
              library = ['steam_api'])
    ])


setup(
  name = 'Teste',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  packages=[],
  ext_modules = extensions
)
```

Obviously isn't working because I get this when building:

```
steamtypes.h:107:15: error: variably modified 'Salt_t' at file scope


typedef uint8 Salt_t[ k_cubSaltSize ];
               ^
steamtypes.h:123:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 const GID_t k_TxnIDNil = k_GIDNil;
```

Etc...

Test.pyx:

```
from libcpp cimport bool

cdef extern from "steam_api_flat_test.h":
bool SteamAPI_ISteamUser_BLoggedOn(ssize_t instancePtr);
```

Comment: You should include your `test.pyx` here, otherwise it is hard to give any help; [mcve].

Comment: I don't know why test.pyx is that important since this is a linking problem.

^ test.pyx on OP

Comment: Those errors are from the compilation phase, not linking.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QcGrhwvY

Comment: steam_api_flat_test: http://pastebin.com/HBnVrV4B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors likes

```
steamclientpublic.h:465:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class CSteamID
```

indicate that C++ compiler is needed, which can be specified in *setup.py*

```
Extension("test", ["test.pyx"],
          language="c++",
          library = ['steam_api'])
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks that solved some problems!
Bear with me that I'm like a 0 with C/C++, so basic stuff probably will cause me some trouble: 
http://pastebin.com/fvrTTD4J

Comment: Okay I converted the strncpy_s to strncpy and fixed this issue.

Comment: Last question, is there a way to call the functions on steam_api_flat_test.h, without using a .cpp file? (On Python)